# Há algo de errado ao criar um projeto React

Tags: node.js, react, npm, módulo-ecmascript

Ao tentar criar um novo projeto React a ação não é completada. Vou anexar prints com erros e versões. Ja testei muitos comandos que vi na internet, mas nenhum resolveu meu problema. Inclusive desinstalei e reinstalei o Node com a ultima versão recomendada. (Quero deixar claro que sou iniciante na área e peço um pouco de paciência ao tentar me ajudar).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já deixei mais de 2 dias o notbook ligado pra ver se rodava e criava, porém não funcionou.
As versões são essas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sem nenhuma mensagem fica difícil tentar ajudá-la...

Comment: Foi o que meu professor me respondeu. Mas eu esperei pra ver qualquer mensagem e continuou com esse Done.

Comment: Pelos prints não tem erro nenhum, apenas warnings. Você tentou rodar a aplicação?

Comment: Tentei sim, porém ele não cria o arquivo index.js que, segundo o professor, deveria ser criado com o comando npx create-react-app todo. 
O que é criado são os seguintes:
node_modules
 package.json
 yarn.lock

Quando dou npm start aparece:
npm ERR! missing script: start

Comment: Vi que tem um problema se a instalação do create-react-app foi feita globalmente. Pode tentar desinstalar a versão global com npm uninstall -g create-react-app  e depois reinstalar localmente?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso! Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Para garantir todas as possibilidades, faça o seguinte.
Limpe o cache do node

```
npm cache clean
```

Depois, desinstale o create-react-app de seu modulo global

```
npm uninstall create-next-app -g
```

Delete a pasta de criação da sua aplicação e crie novamente com o comando no npx

```
npx create-react-app todo
```

Comment: É amigo, continua com o mesmo erro. Mas obrigada pela tentativa